# Fishpig Magento and qTranslate integration. (hooks and filters)

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, locale, fishpig

I am working on getting qTranslate working (specifically the mqTranslate plugin). When using the Magento theme to display the blog, I notice that the functions.php in the wordpress theme appears to be bypassed.

How can I use hooks and filters with Fishpig to get the qTranslate plugin functions to filter the post title and content? Overriding the fishpig base/default/template files on a one by one basis seems counter productive.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Because Wordpress doesn't use the Magento framework, my assumption is the qTranslate extension built to translate Magento blocks won't work with the integrated Wordpress functions.

Comment: This is the qTranslate for Wordpress

Comment: Oh I see.  I believe the Fishpig plugin queries the Wordpress database directly and injects the data into a Magento block, so any 3rd party modifications to the data on the Wordpress end would be bypassed when used on the Magento side.

Comment: Makes sense, using a model I suppose. I was mostly trying to see if there was a common place where customization can be written in without having to override or extend with a rewrite, as that is also counter productive when it comes to updating the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axel is correct as the extension connects directly to the WordPress database and extracts the data and displays in via Magento models, blocks, controllers etc. As a result, it would take an additional Magento extension that adds support for the qTranslate WordPress plugin.

Another way to accomplish a multi-lingual blog controlled by WordPress in Magento would be as follows:

Setup a WordPress Multisite installation in a sub-directory of your Magento site called 'wp'. Create a different blog for each of your languages. Using [Magento WordPress Multisite Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/multisite/) you could then associate each of these blogs to the appropriate Magento store view. As the customer changes the store view, the language will be changed to what ever language is set for the new store view and the correct blog will be displayed.

This is the method that the majority of people currently use but I will look into adding support for qTranslate via an add-on extension.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the response. I was working on using regular expression filters in the default post renderer template, the data is already available to the model, all that needs to be added for qtranslate is regex filters based on store views, then writing that into the adminhtml. But I will also look into the multisite integration to see if it will be a better fit.